Creating a custom urdf (and launch file?) to allow rviz/moveit to plan for ur3e with robotiq hand-e gripper?
Good morning everyone! I'm using a ur3e with a robotiq hand-e gripper, trying to get it set up in ROS2 Iron so that we can control the arm from MoveIt.  I've installed the ur_robot_driver via apt and I can control it per the UR tutorial, but the planner does not know about the gripper (as it is not reflected in the ur_3e URDF) so makes plans that include collisions between the gripper and the arm or the gripper and environment objects.
(Controlling the gripper itself from within ROS2 is a separate issue, as it appears that Robotiq does not support ROS anymore, but that is a tomorrow-problem.)
I know that changing the URDF within the ur_robot_driver package is not correct (since it would mess with updates and such), and I've seen systems that call on component URDF and launch files to launch multiple robots within a larger robot system, but I am not sure how to create that or what the minimum-viable-package looks like that would launch the ur3e.launch.py file but using a custom URDF file.
